# Does "$f(x)+f(y)<f(x+y)$" imply the convexity?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, functional-equations

For a function $f:\mathbf{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_+,x\mapsto f(x)$, assume that :

- $f(0^+)=0$
- $\forall\ x,y>0:f(x)+f(y)<f(x+y)$
- $\forall\ 0<x<y: f(x)<f(y)$

For example, $f(x)=2^x-1$.

Must $f$ be convex? If not, is there any counterexample?

I tried to calculate the second derivative of $f$ and prove that it's always positive, but I failed. Moreover, even if it's proved, it's not enough to solve the problem ($f$ may be non-differentiable).

Obviously, it's impossible to prove $f(x)+f(y)>2f(\frac{x+y}2)$ or other similar conclusions, so the Cauchy trick is hard to be available.

Comment: Why is $f(x)+f(y)>2f(\tfrac{x+y}{2})$ obviously impossible to prove?

Comment: If I'm correct: let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 & 0\leq x\leq 1\\ x^2+1 & x>1,\end{cases}$$ then $f$ satisfies all conditions; but $f$ is not convex since it is not continuous.

Comment: @IraeVid No, every convex function on $(0,\infty)$ is continuous.

Comment: @IraeVid Not relevant. Here the function is from $\Bbb R^+$ to $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Oops sorry. In that case @Feng would you mind writing that into an answer?

Comment: @IraeVid Indeed, I wonder what will happen if we further require the continuity of $f$. I think an answer involving continuous functions will be better. So I just leave my example as a comment.

Comment: Try a strategy from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911357/is-a-positive-monotone-and-sub-additive-function-concave) @Feng if you can.

Comment: The question has been dealt with in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35669/subadditive-implies-concave (here we have: superadditive implies convex, which is the same when taking $-f$). Counterexamples exist but are not easy to construct.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523747/42969 for an example that superadditivity does not imply convexity.

Comment: Using the link @SarveshRavichandranIyer suggested, here is an explicity counterexample: $$f(x)=x[(x-1)^3+1]=x^4-3x^3+3x^2, \qquad x\geq0.$$ This $f$ satisfies the conditions since $f(x)/x$ is strictly increasing; but $f$ is not convex, since $$f''(x)=6(2x-1)(x-1).$$ Some other links are listed above to make this post as a duplicate, so I still leave my example as a comment here.

Comment: @Feng The function $f(x) = \min(x^2, (x-1)^2 + 1)$ also works.